# How to share image to Snapchat use urlScheme?

Tags: ios, iphone

I know the scheme `snapchat://add/[username]`, but how to transfer and share image by `urlScheme`? What is the `scheme key`?

Like use `UIActivityViewController` to share image, but I don't want to use it.

I've ever seen this function in 'Monkey' App, just like `urlScheme`.

Comment: Well, it maybe an image http url in the scheme. But I didn't find the key.

Comment: You can't, Snapchat doesn't support extra URL schemes other than /add