# How to share image to Snapchat from my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, snapchat

How to share an image (local from Gallery or any from the internet with url) to Snapchat from my Flutter app?

Is there any Snapchat urlScheme to do that, as was asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814120/how-to-share-image-to-snapchat-use-urlscheme)?

Or can I achieve it with this [app_utils plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/app_utils) as

```dart
await AppUtils.launchApp(
        iosUrlScheme: 'snapchat://',
        androidPackage: 'com.snapchat.android',
        params: {
          'imageUrl': 'path to my image'
        },
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [snapkit](https://pub.dev/packages/snapkit) package to share images using snapkit.share() function

```dart
snapkit.share(SnapchatMediaType.PHOTO,
  image: ImageProvider,
  sticker: SnapchatSticker?,
  caption: String?,
  attachmentUrl: String?
);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ahmed! I've implemented it with this package after a bunch of settings in the Snapchat Developer Portal and the plugin's settings which you can find here 
 https://github.com/TimmyRB/snapkit/wiki/iOS-Installation